# ASP.NET MVC Partial View with View Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I Try to list in the same Create page the products I put to the same invoice. So I need insert my supplier invoices, off course in this invoice i have many products and I need to list in the same page where I create this invoice, so as soon as I insert the product it is appear on my list, I try to use partial view, but i can't find the solution.

My controller

```
  [Area("***")]
    public class PurchaseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public PurchaseController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Purchases> objPurchaseList = _unitOfWork.Purchase.GetAll(includeProperties:"Suppliers").ToList();
            return View(objPurchaseList);
        }

        public IActionResult _CreatePartialView(string? invoice)
        {
            PurchaseVM purchaseVM = new()
            {
                purchases = new(),

              
            };

            if (invoice==null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }

            List<Purchases> purchaseList = _unitOfWork.Purchase.GetAll().Where(u => u.PurchaseInvoice == invoice).ToList();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
        //GET
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            PurchaseVM purchaseVM = new()
            {
                purchases = new(),

                GroupList = _unitOfWork.Group.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = u.GroupName,
                    Value = u.GroupId.ToString()
                }),

                SupplierList = _unitOfWork.Supplier.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = u.SupplierName,
                    Value = u.SupplierId.ToString()
                }),

                ProductList = _unitOfWork.Product.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = u.ProductName,
                    Value = u.ProductId.ToString()
                }),
            };

            return View(purchaseVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Purchases obj)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Purchase.Add(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"]= "Product added successfully.";
                return View(obj);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}

My Partial View

@model IEnumerable<Purchases>


@foreach (var obj in Model.GroupBy(u => u.PurchaseInvoice))
{
    <tr>
        <td width="15%">
            @obj.First().PurcahseDate
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            @obj.First().PurchaseInvoice
        </td>
        <td width="35%">
            @obj.First().Suppliers.SupplierName
        </td>
        <td width="15%" style="text-align:right">
            @obj.Sum(u => u.PurchaseTotal)
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
            <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                <a asp-controller="Purchase" asp-action="Edit" style="width:120px" asp-route-id="@obj.First().PurchaseInvoice"
                   class="btn btn-primary mx-2"> <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</a>
                <a asp-controller="Purchase" asp-action="Delete" style="width:125px" asp-route-id="@obj.First().PurchaseInvoice"
                   class="btn btn-danger mx-2"> <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Delete</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

My ViewModel

namespace SysComm.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class PurchaseVM
    {
        public Purchases purchases { get;set; }

        public List<Purchases> purchaseList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductList { get; set; }
    }
}


Part off My View

            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Id
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Date
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Customer Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Customer Phone
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Action
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <partial name="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Purchase/_CreatePartialView.cshtml" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use razor as a sample.
First thing you need define your partial view.
For instance in shared folder. Let's name it "PagerPartial".

At the top of your define the object you want to use like this:

```
@model someclass
```

After definition you can user this model like this in your razor page like this:

```
<b>@Model.SomeProperty</b> item(s) listed
```

After you complete your partial view you can use it in your other razor pages like this:

```
@model SomeRazorProjectName.Pages.IndexModel

<div>
@await Html.PartialAsync("PagerPartial", Model.SomePropertyWithTypeOfSomeClass)
</div>
```

Note that **"IndexModel"** is the class of my razor page and **"SomePropertyWithTypeOfSomeClass"** is a property of type **"someclass"** defined in my page model.

So, for you scenario you need to pass full product details (or just the id and let the partial view handle rest) to partial view to display as a row. You can adapt this according to your needs, but the basics same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ozan, your method is very interesting, but wouldn't you need call handling in you controller, since i want to insert the product and show it right after insertion? In my method I just have problem because when I try create , I have not valid object in my ModelState.

Comment: Actually long time ago I gave up using controllers (mvc) for my asp.net projects. Currently this sample demonstrates usage of partial views in ASP.NET Razor pages. 

But, anyway logic is very similar. If you do not have a valid object you need to populate it in your controller before passing it to your view and then pass it to your partial view. Hope this is clear. Please do not hesitate to ask more if it is not.

Comment: If you need some dynamic interface you may utilize javascript to populate partial view. For instance here is latest news is a partial view and populated via javascript.
http://ozanbayram.com/site/en (Note that this site is very old and created with asp.net mvc) I will try to find source of this and remember it.

Answer (score 0):

-> I think you are trying to display a list of purchases on the same page , in you create new purchase invoice and you want to update list dynamically according to new purchases added.

-> Check your AJAX Url (/Purchase/_CreatePartialView) according to your application routing configuration.

-> Modify your code :-

-> PartialView(_CreatePartialView.cshtml) :-

```
@model IEnumerable<Purchases>

@foreach (var purchase in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@purchase.PurchaseId</td>
    <td>@purchase.PurchaseDate</td>
    <td>@purchase.Suppliers.SupplierName</td>
    <td>@purchase.Suppliers.SupplierPhone</td>
    <td>
        <!-- Action buttons -->
   </td>
 </tr>
}
```

-> Main View (where you create purchase invoice) and add script to load initially and update dynamically.
code:-

```
<div id="purchaseListContainer">
<partial name="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Purchase/_CreatePartialView.cshtml" 
 model="Model.purchaseList" />
</div>

 <!-- Script to update purchase list dynamically -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    updatePurchaseList();

    // Function to update the purchase list dynamically
    function updatePurchaseList() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Purchase/_CreatePartialView',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (partialView) {
                $('#purchaseListContainer').html(partialView);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
       }
    });
 </script>
```

-> PurchaseController :-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Purchases obj)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    _unitOfWork.Purchase.Add(obj);
    _unitOfWork.Save();
    TempData["success"] = "Product added successfully.";

    // Return PartialView to update the purchase list
    return PartialView("_CreatePartialView", 
    _unitOfWork.Purchase.GetAll());
   }

  return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Henil, thanks to help me , so I try like you post and in the open the purchase return the error on _CreatePartialView "'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
"